# AcquireDiskLeaseFailed issue in MS azure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I am using the multiple cloud computers provided by microsoft azure.

While using it, I removed all the virtual machines in azure by my mistake.

So I tried to recover it using `vhd` files by following the manual but it also failed. The error message was `AcquireDiskLeaserFailed` and it is relevant to the blob. However, I didn't know how to solve this issue although the error message find the cause.

I would appreciate it if you could find the my issue.

Thanks.

Comment: How did you recover your VMs? Have you tried this template to deploy them?https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/templates/201-vm-os-disk-and-data-disk-existing-vnet/

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT I tried, but failed to recover it. The message shows that blob is already occupied. However, I didn't find the solution, since I am not quite familiar with the MS azure and I don't know what the blob is.

Comment: The Blob contains the vhd file. I assume that you've create VM from the Vhd, so it is occupied. Try to delete the old or failed one and deploy it again.

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT Thanks for the reply. I found the pages indicating how to delete the blob (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/delete-blob). However, I am having a hard time how to run the command that the site provide and I don't have a idea how to identify my existing bob. I really appreciate it if you could kindly help me how to delete bob..

Comment: HI,@sclee1 . Sorry for my unclear comment. The last comment means that you can delete the old VMs which may occupied your Blob.  The Blob contains your VHD file . If you delete the blob, the VHD will disappear.  I did a test in my lab to recover a VM from a VHD with this template, and it works. If you can give us more details about your issue, I believe that we can resolved it. :)

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT Thanks. I can recovered the worker nodes that I have deleted. I can see the VMs on the virtual machine dashboard. However, I cannot connect it with the putty even though the machines are given the public ip by MS azure. I tried to connect to the VMs via putty but failed. I very much appreciate it if you could help me one more time :D